# Angular 2 general functionanlity location in project

Tags: angular

In angular 2, where in the project should I put general functions?
functions like date manipulations, string manipulations etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a service to hold general functions like the ones that you listed above. I then inject that service into the components that need to use the functions.

For example I have a utils serivice...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UtilsService {

    public cleanString(input: string): string {

        if (input) {
            input = input.replace(/&/g, '');
        }
        return input;
    }
}
}
```

And this is injected into a component as so...

```
constructor( private _utilsService: UtilsService) {
}
```

The component can then access the cleanString function like so...

```
_utilsService.cleanString("some value");
```